# Azure Databricks: create audit trail for who ran what query at what moment

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks

We have an audit requirement to provide insight into who executed what query at what moment in Azure Databricks. The Azure Databricks / Spark UI / Jobs tab already lists the Spark jobs executed including the query done and the time it was submitted. But it does not include who executed the query.

1. Is there an API we can use with Azure Databricks to query these Spark job details shown in the UI? (The [Databricks REST API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/index.html) does not seem to provide this, but maybe I'm overlooking something)
2. Is there a way we can determine who created the Spark job (using an API)

Thanks,
Gero

Answer (score 2):

## 1. Access the Spark API

a. Driver node (internal) access the Azure Databricks Spark api:

```
import requests

driverIp = spark.conf.get('spark.driver.host')
port = spark.conf.get("spark.ui.port")
url = F"http://{driverIp}:{port}/api/v1/applications"
r = requests.get(url, timeout=3.0)
r.status_code, r.text
```

If for example you received this error message from public API:
`PERMISSION_DENIED: Traffic on this port is not permitted`

b. External Access to the Azure Databricks Spark API:

```
import requests
import json
"""
  Program access to Databricks Spark UI. 
  
  Works external to Databricks environment or running within.
  Requires a Personal Access Token. Treat this like a password, do not store in a notebook. Please refer to the Secrets API.
  This Python code requires F string support.

"""

# https://<databricks-host>/driver-proxy-api/o/0/<cluster_id>/<port>/api/v1/applications/<application-id-from-master-spark-ui>/stages/<stage-id>
port = spark.conf.get("spark.ui.port")
clusterId = spark.conf.get("spark.databricks.clusterUsageTags.clusterId")
host = "eastus2.azuredatabricks.net"
workspaceId = "999999999999111"  # follows the 'o=' in the databricks URLs or zero
token = "dapideedeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeef68ee3"  # Personal Access token

url = F"https://{host}/driver-proxy-api/o/{workspaceId}/{clusterId}/{port}/api/v1/applications/?status=running"
r = requests.get(url, auth=("token", token))

# print Application list response
print(r.status_code, r.text)

applicationId = r.json()[0]['id'] # assumes only one response

url = F"https://{host}/driver-proxy-api/o/{workspaceId}/{clusterId}/{port}/api/v1/applications/{applicationId}/jobs"
r = requests.get(url, auth=("token", token))

print(r.status_code, r.json())
```

## 2. Sorry, no, not at this time.

The cluster logs would be where you'd look, but the user identity is not there.

To vote and track this idea: https://ideas.databricks.com/ideas/DBE-I-313
How to get to the Ideas portal: https://docs.databricks.com/ideas.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply Douglas. 
Related question, do you know if the Spark Monitoring REST API can be accessed (from/via Databricks)? (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api)

Comment: Re-answered factoring in the two parts of the question.

Comment: Thanks. I tried both examples, accessing the internal API results in a `Connection refused` response. 

And accessing the external API results in a `403 PERMISSION_DENIED: Traffic on this port is not permitted`

Is there a config setting we should enable to make access possible?

Comment: Perhaps your network security groups are restricted, lots of companies do that now. 
I don't know how to override on the 403 error, I received the same error on Azure Databricks. The strategy is to find the spark driver java process and attach to the same IP and port. I tried approach #1 on the localhost interface in tcp6 without much luck.
You can use the `%sh netstat -anltp` to fish around for the right interface, address, protocol and port.

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer from [Douglas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7379644/douglas-m) I came up with this function to use inside Databricks Notebooks and get some information about the cached RDDs:

I hope it helps. I was looking information about 2h on this topic.

```py
def get_databricks_rdd_info():

    import requests, json

    # Get Spark Context
    sc = spark.sparkContext
    # Get App Id (Notebook is attached to it)
    app_id = sc._jsc.sc().applicationId()
    # Where is my driver
    driver_ip = spark.conf.get('spark.driver.host')
    port = spark.conf.get("spark.ui.port")
    # Compose the query to the Spark UI API
    url = f"http://{driver_ip}:{port}/api/v1/applications/{app_id}/storage/rdd"

    # Make request
    r = requests.get(url, timeout=3.0)

    if r.status_code == 200:
        # Compose results
        df = spark.createDataFrame([json.dumps(r) for r in r.json()], T.StringType())
        json_schema = spark.read.json(df.rdd.map(lambda row: row.value)).schema
        df = df.withColumn('value', F.from_json(F.col('value'), json_schema))
        df = df.selectExpr('value.*')
        
        # Generate summary
        df_summary = (df
                      .withColumn('Name', F.element_at(F.split(F.col('name'), ' '), -1))
                      .withColumn('Cached', F.round(F.lit(100) * F.col('numCachedPartitions')/F.col('numPartitions'), 2))
                      .withColumn('Memory GB', F.round(F.col('memoryUsed')*1e-9, 2))
                      .withColumn('Disk GB', F.round(F.col('diskUsed')*1e-9, 2))
                      .withColumnRenamed('numPartitions', '# Partitions')

                      .select([
                          'Name',
                          'id',
                          'Cached',
                          'Memory GB',
                          'Disk GB',
                          '# Partitions',
                      ]))
    else:
        print('Some error happened, code:', r.status_code)
        df = None
        df_summary = None
        
        
    return df, df_summary
```

You can use it inside Databricks Notebooks as:

```py
df_rdd_info, df_summary = get_databricks_rdd_info()
display(df_summary)
```